# How to make scripts excutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

How I transform my program into an executable (.exe)? It has 3 .py files and images.
Made with `tkinter` and python 3.7, I saw that people used py2exe or pyinstaller but I don't know how to do that.

[image: check image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use py2exe but options like cx_freeze and pyinstaller are also out there. What goes for mac i beleive there exist a module called py2app ;)

to use py2exe you must first have python 3.4 since it hasnt't recently been updated. After that you need to make a file in which you write

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=["yourfile"])
```

then you need to run the file with the following command - i called the file setup.txt here.

```
py -3.4 setup.txt install
```

remember to write .py if you used a python file and then you just need one more step

```
py -3.4 setup.txt py2exe
```

and ofcause remeber you need to have py2exe installed. If you haven't before you do anything write in to the comandoprompt

```
pip install py2exe
```

The exe will then be found i the dist folder.

imported libraries are always triggy though i think i remember that last time i had to convert tkinter to .exe i had to use cx_freeze.

Comment: ok men, but if i have python 3.7, not if better use Pyinstaller? or i need degrade python to 3.4?